# Not all iPHone push notifications delivered to iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am developing iPhone application, application registered for receive push notifications.
I send push notification to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com from server,all ok, but sometimes push notifications not delivered to iPhone (size of notification message is correct, < 256 bytes). Why? Maybe exists limitations for iPhone sandbox(for example count notifications in one hour) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no guarantee of delivery of push notifications. In addition to other potential causes  consider this section of the [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html)

> Quality of Service
>
> Apple Push Notification Service includes a default Quality of Service
>   (QoS) component that performs a store-and-forward function. If APNs
>   attempts to deliver a notification but the device is offline, the QoS
>   stores the notification. It retains only one notification per
>   application on a device: the last notification received from a
>   provider for that application. When the offline device later
>   reconnects, the QoS forwards the stored notification to the device.
>   The QoS retains a notification for a limited period before deleting
>   it.

If a device is offline (either turned off or just unreachable) then it will receive at most a single push notification you attempt to send to your application during that time.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the fault is on your network provider which is unable to deliver notifications.same problem i was facing with my device when it was connected to wifi, When I connected it to 3g network all notifications were received instantly.